# ajax request not working when build app using build.phonegap.com

Tags: php, android, ajax, phonegap-build, html-framework-7

i tried for one week all kind of solutions but nothing work , i dont know how i can debug my release app, in debug mode app every thing works fine!  this is my html code

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob: filesystem: ws: gap://ready file: cdvfile: https://ssl.gstatic.com *; style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; img-src * data: 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * 'unsafe-inline'; frame-src *; worker-src *; child-src *;">

$.post("https://xxxxx/api/").done(function (data) {                             
   console.log(data);
})
```

config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="*" />
```

php code :

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$sendData[status] = 'ERROR';
$sendData[message] = 'no action command';
echo json_encode($sendData);    
exit();
```

what i missed here ?

Comment: its work fine ... i think the problem was cache issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried including the whitelist plugin on your app on the `config.xml` file

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
cordova prepare
```

You can read about it here : https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

Answer (score 0):

DOM7 can not be accessed with $ while working with Framework7 due conflict issue. Instead of '$' use '$$'. DOM7 is assigned to $$ at the time of app initialisation. you can check that. Check the below link for more information http://framework7.io/docs/dom7.html

Comment: I said it works fine in debug mode ... i wll try using DOM7